# Random Error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null

Tags: java, javafx, illegalargumentexception

When using `WebView JavaFx` and trying to load certain websites, I got the following error:

> Oct 08, 2016 1:38:30 PM com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader doRun
>   WARNING: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol
>   = http host = null    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:176)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1099)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>     at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.close(URLLoader.java:591)   at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.doRun(URLLoader.java:173)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$run$91(URLLoader.java:128)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.run(URLLoader.java:127)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My code was:

```
WebView myBrowser = new WebView();
myWebEngine = myBrowser.getEngine();
myWebEngine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> observableValue, Throwable oldException,
                Throwable exception)
    {
        System.out.println("WebView encountered an exception loading a page: " + exception);
    }
});
myBrowser.setPrefSize(1600, 900);
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the insecure 'solution' and investigate the actual problem: the handshake failure. You can't deploy this code in production, so using it anywhere is just a waste of time and a distraction from real work. Start by printing the entire stack trace of the handshake problem, instead of just the top line.

Comment: I updated my question and removed the 'solution'. Instead of the SSL handshake failure, I get the above stated error